# How to use global variables in CSS-Modules?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I'm busy learning React with CSS-Modules and I don't quite understand how one would store variables? For example, in Sass you're able to do this:

```
// _variables.scss
$primary-color: #f1f1f1; 

// heading.scss
@import './variables';
.heading {
  color: $primary-color
}
```

How do you achieve this in CSS Modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way could be to use dependencies. For example,

```
// variables.css
.primaryColor {
  color: #f1f1f1
}

// heading.css
.heading {
  composes: primaryColor from "./variables.css"
}
```

See more detailed information here: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#dependencies

If you're using webpack there are more examples here: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#composing-css-classes

Also if you are using webpack you can still use Sass with CSS modules.

Comment: While composition is an option, I would advise following Icharbon's answer. With postcss you have actual variable support, and will help keep code DRY'er. CSS Modules and Sass can be used together though, so I'd prefer Sass variables over the `@Value` syntax mentioned.

Comment: composition !== variables.

Comment: While this works for this example, this answer is not the answer to the question "how can you use global values with css modules" haha. For example, what if I wanted to use this color for the background color as well as color?

Answer (score 68):

This is how you do it with vanilla CSS Modules

```
// vars.css
:root {
  --color-black: #222;
}


// myComponent.module.css
@import './vars.css';

.component {
  color: var(--color-black);
}
```

Answer (score 23):

The CSS-Modules documentation mentions variables here:
https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/docs/values-variables.md

With this you can import variables as so:

```
@value colors: "../../main/colors.css";
@value primary, secondary, tertiary from colors;
```

which can be used in your css:

```
.main {
    background-color: tertiary;
    border-top: 30px solid primary;
}
```

To make this work `postcss-loader` and `postcss-modules-values` need to be added to your webpack config. See below:

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                        localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: [postcssModulesValues]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: `localIdentName` has now moved inside modules. You may wanna do: `modules: {auto: true, localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]",}`

Comment: Any idea how a @value can be used in a CSS calc() ?

For example this throws and error:
"@value margin: 10px;

.someclass{
    width: calc(100% - margin);
}"

Answer (score 4):

If you add the root css variables in `index.css` you can access these globally without using `@import`

This is assuming that `index.css` is imported in the `src/App.js` file as the default file structure.

css modules are scoped meaning that the variables inside them are local, but that does not mean you cannot access variables from a global css file.

**Example One**

Let's say this is our `index.css`

```
:root {
  --header-width: 95vw;
  --border-radius-one: 5px;
}
body {
  background-color: #261d54;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

We can then access this root css variables like so:

```
#header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: var(--header-width);
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-one);
}
```

Now, if you would like to modify these variables from the script, so that you can make them dynamic you can use the [setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) JS method to set a new value for a CSS property.

So, the way you would do this in React is by creating a function to change the property and implement an `onClick` in JSX

**Example Two**

```
function changeFontSize(size){
   document.documentElement.setProperty('--font-size', size)
}

return(
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => changeFontSize('18px')}>
      set font size to 18px
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => changeFontSize('12px')}>
      set font size to 12px
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

If you want to read about **documentElement** [go here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement).